# I am getting a segmentation fault on subset sum problem in C

Tags: c, algorithm, subset-sum

I need to handle a subset sum problem. It needs to figure out if a subset of an array can sum up to required value. 
Sample input 
9: 3 34 4 12 5 2 
9 = 5 + 4

However, I am getting a segmentation fault and some warnings below

```
logParse.c: In function ‘findSubset’:
logParse.c:37:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘subsetSum’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    subsetSum(set, subSet, size, 0, 0, 0, sum);
    ^
logParse.c:21:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
 void subsetSum(int set[], int subSet[], int n, int subSize, int total, int nodeCount ,int sum) {
      ^
gcc logParse.c -o logParse
logParse.c: In function ‘findSubset’:
logParse.c:37:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘subsetSum’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    subsetSum(set, subSet, size, 0, 0, 0, sum);
    ^
logParse.c:21:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
 void subsetSum(int set[], int subSet[], int n, int subSize, int total, int nodeCount ,int sum) {
```

Here is my faulty code

```
        void displaySubset(int subSet[], int size) {

           int i;
           int subset[size];
           for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              printf("%d ",subset[i]);
              //printf(" ");
           }
           printf("\n");
        }

        void subsetSum(int set[], int subSet[], int n, int subSize, int total, int nodeCount ,int sum) {
           int i;
           if( total == sum) {
              displaySubset(subSet, subSize);     //print the subset
              subsetSum(set,subSet,n,subSize-1,total-set[nodeCount],nodeCount+1,sum);     //for other subsets
              return;
           }else {
              for(i = nodeCount; i < n; i++ ) {     //find node along breadth
                 subSet[subSize] = set[i];
                 subsetSum(set,subSet,n,subSize+1,total+set[i],i+1,sum);     //do for next node in depth
              }
           }
        }

        void findSubset(int set[], int size, int sum) {
           int subSet[size];      //create subset array to pass parameter of subsetSum
           subsetSum(set, subSet, size, 0, 0, 0, sum);
        }

        int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

                int weights[] = {10, 7, 5, 18, 12, 20, 15};
                int size = 7;
                findSubset(weights, size, 35);
                return 0;
        }
```

Here is my faulty output

```
    1173794464 32765 4197334 
    1173794464 32765 4197334 
    1173794544 32765
```

Please help me how to fix my code, thanks

Comment: at findSubset function, when calling subsetSum, you're calling with an array of int* when actually it expects an array of int. declare int subSet[size] instead of int *subSet[size].

Comment: `int subset[size]; for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              printf("%d ",subset[i]);  }` displays random data.  Why print an uninitialized array?  Is this code you wrote or someones else's code you are trying to debug?

Comment: @chux https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Subset-Sum-Problem I got it from here, I need to implement this algorithm to my project, I will try to make the child processes to handle subtasks

Comment: @omermuhit Your link has `void displaySubset(int subSet[], int size) {
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      cout << subSet[i] << "  ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}`/  Why do you want your code to print uninitialized array `subset[]` rather than `subSet[]`?

Comment: I have just noticed and it worked thanks @chux

Comment: Did you fix the code in your question? There's no point in answering this now if the code has no problem.

Comment: In a perfect world you would have worked on the warnings of the compiler before daring to post a question here. ;-)